# How to change the application to open pdf file in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-reader, evince

In Firefox, when I clicked a pdf file in website, I would be asked to download the pdf file or open the pdf file in  evince running outside Firefox.

Since I install Adobe Reader, whenever I clicked a pdf link, the pdf will be opened in it running inside Firefox.

I feel it is now running more slowly than before. Is it possible to change which application to open pdf from within Firefox?

Thanks and regards!

P.S. My OS is Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I do in Windows is disable the Adobe Reader Firefox extension.  The latest version really sucks.

That should then let you download the PDFs again.  It may want to open them in Adobe Reader still, but changing the default application associated with PDFs in Ubuntu should cure that.

Right-click on a PDF file and select "Open With Other Application".  Choose your preferred application and check the "Remember this application for PDF Document files" setting.

Comment: Thanks! But, Under Tools -> add-ons -> extensions, I don't have the "Adobe Reader Firefox extension".

Comment: It is in Tools > Add-ons > Plugins